# Find local minima of series

Tags: r, series, minima

There is a series 8,7,6,5,6,7,8,7,6,7,8 which has local minima at 5 and 6.

How to get this using R?

Comment: This series is taking double dip if plotted, at 5 and 6. That is what I meant by. Corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(zoo)

x <- c(8,7,6,5,6,7,8,7,6,7,8)

# eliminate runs
r <- rle(x)
r$lengths[] <- 1
xx <- inverse.rle(r)        

xx[ rollapply(c(Inf, xx, Inf), 3, function(x) x[2] < min(x[-2])) ]
## [1] 5 6
```

If we knew that `x` had no runs, as is the case in the question's example, we could omit the three lines that eliminate runs and replace `xx` in the last statement with `x`.  Use `-Inf` in place of both occurrences of `Inf` if you don't want to consider endpoints.

It is assumed that the input `c(2, 1, 1, 3)` should result in output of 1 once.

Comment: Thanks. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no runs, we can simply check the difference with the lagging and leading number:

```
library(dplyr)
x[x - lag(x) < 0 & x - lead(x) < 0]
```

Gives:

```
[1] 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried by using without any package and got the results.

```
series<-c(8,7,6,5,6,7,8,7,6,7,8)
#We have local minima at 5 and 6.
#Check if series is decreasing in the begining itself
series[2]<series[1]
#If so let us check for minima.
#First check if you have multiple minima
less<-numeric()
#Fill first position and write a loop to check rest of positions.
less<-1
for(i in 2:length(series)){
less[i]<-ifelse(series[i-1]>=series[i],1,0)
}
#First occurance of 0 after 1
checkless<-numeric()
#Fill first position and write a loop to check rest of positions.
checkless<-1
for(i in 2:length(less)){
  checkless[i]<-ifelse(less[i-1]==0,1,less[i])
}
#Indexes where 0 exists indicates the change in signs.
which(checkless==0)
#Local minima exists once index before change
which(checkless==0)-1
series[which(checkless==0)-1]
#Check how many cases exists
length(series[which(checkless==0)])
#If number of such cases greater than 1 then we have multiple minima in the series
length(series[which(checkless==0)])>1
```